# Не корректно ищет максимальный и минимальный элемент массива

Tags: c, массивы, if, while

**Вводится последовательность произвольных чисел, 0 — конец последовательности. Определить отношение минимального и максимального элементов друг к другу.**

Ввожу несколько чисел, например - 2, 4, 6, 1, хочу закончить последовательность нулем, последовательность заканчивается, и мне выводит минимальный - 0, и максимальный - 6, вроде бы все правильно, но, минимальный должен быть 1, а не нулем, почему так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int i, max, min, mas[255];
    float z;
    max = 0;
    min = 0;
    float q = 0;
    while(mas[i++] != 0){
        printf("element mas[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%d", &mas[i]);
        if(mas[i] > max){
            max=mas[i];
        }
        else if(mas[i] < min){
            min=mas[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", min);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: До того как проверить введённый элемент на ноль вы запускаете его в общую обработку.

Comment: Начинать с `while(mas[i++] != 0)` (даже если вы проинициализруете  `i` (сейчас этого нет)) абсолютно не правильно. Лучше написать вот так -- `int rc; for (i = 0; (rc = scanf("%d", &mas[i])) == 1 && mas[i] != 0; i++) { ... `

Comment: Только инициализацию max и min придется втащить внутрь цикла -- `if (i == 0) max = min = mas[0]; else { if (max < mas[i]) ...` и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Замените

```
while(mas[i++] != 0){
```

на

```
for(i = 0; scanf("%d",&mas[i]) && mas[i] != 0; i++){
```

Так вы и `i` инициализируете, и с правильным элементом работать будете.

Comment: проверка на нуль должна быть внутри цикла после **scanf**, а не в начале

Comment: @AlexGlebe Да, спасибо, постарался исправиться.

Comment: интересный манёвр с `&&`, даже есть защита на правильный ввод.

Comment: @AlexGlebe на том и стоим! :)